# Flutter & GraphQL Returning Data in Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, graphql

Been building an app using Flutter and calling to GraphQL database. At the moment, I have just been accessing data by wrapping the following in a stateless widget:

```
return Query(
        options: QueryOptions(
          document: gql(exampleGraphQL),
        ),
        builder: (QueryResult result, {fetchMore, refetch}) {
          if (result.hasException) {
            return Text(result.exception.toString());
          }
          if (result.isLoading) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          var exampleData = result.data?['example'];

          return Scaffold(...
```

But now, I am attempting to make a sortable DataTable, and I need to access the data in a stateful widget (or access it in a simple class) that cannot return a scaffold and just returns the data I want to access. I have looked for hours and cannot find how to access GraphQl data without returning a widget. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Plz include a whole bit of code! I.e. one that can be copy-pasted into a Dart pad or IDE and run on our side. That will make it much easier for somebody to answer your qn.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already, try using the graphql package directly:

https://pub.dev/packages/graphql

As far as I can tell, the `Query` widget you're using looks very analogous to the `FutureBuilder` widget. In the same that when you don't need to actually build a widget from the result of a HTTP/fetch web request, you simply use `await` or `.then(...)`. So here, you can you can use the the qraphql client and simply `await` the query to get the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply Jed. I tried exploring this, but in order to use await it needs to be in future function and therefore I need a future builder in order to access the data returned. Thanks